# Disable manual login access to ansible remote user

Tags: linux, ansible

I have a project that requires me to setup a user who can run specific tasks in ansible but said user shouldn't be able to login to the server from the command line.

The reason for this is management wants non administrators to be able to run certain tasks using ansible without direct login access.

In other words, running the task below should be possible for non administrators

```
- hosts: target_server
  remote_user: ansible
  tasks:
  - name: user name
    shell: whoami
    become: no

  changed: [192.168.2.3] => {
"changed": true,
"cmd": "whoami",
"delta": "0:00:00.004776",
"end": "2017-07-20 00:31:36.637252",
"invocation": {
    "module_args": {
        "_raw_params": "whoami",
        "_uses_shell": true,
        "chdir": null,
        "creates": null,
        "executable": null,
        "removes": null,
        "warn": true
    }
},
"rc": 0,
"start": "2017-07-20 00:31:36.632476",
"stderr": "",
"stderr_lines": [],
"stdout": "ansible",
"stdout_lines": [
    "ansible"
]
}
```

However non administrators should not be able to do this.

```
ssh ansible@192.168.2.3
Last login: Thu Jul 20 00:39:11 2017 from 192.168.2.5
[ansible@192.168.2.3 ~]$
```

Any ideas on how to implement this or whether it's even possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a system configuration question, not a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible pretty much requires a login to operate properly due to how it executes shell commands to do its work. I'm not sure you can reasonably restrict a user that's supposed to have a lot of latitude in what it can do.

You may need to use something other than Ansible, maybe a tool that has a server-side agent that runs the jobs, where no external login is needed.

Another approach might be to secure Ansible itself behind some kind of security layer, where the actual Ansible initiation is done by a trusted user that the end-users do not have access to.

This could be via some kind of shell, Python or Ruby script that signals to a background process to perform Ansible tasks, or via a web interface where your people click a button to start the process and the background task takes over.

Comment: "*due to how it executes shell commands to do its work*" What exactly is that "**how**"? For example compared to another "how"...

Comment: @techraf Over `ssh` typically. It uploads scripts, many in Python, representing each task to `/tmp` and then runs them. These verify the operation performed correctly, or in the case of an error are used to capture those errors and forward them back to the `ansible-playbook` client. If you invoke `ansible-playbook` with the `-vvvv` (super-verbose) option it will show you a lot more of what it's doing internally.

Comment: It's not unique, it's just how it works. It also means that locking down shell access pretty much prevents Ansible from doing its work.

Comment: So it's a regular SSH connection, not any special "how". I can think of several ways of limiting user in such a scenario. If you search ServerFault or Unix.SE you'll find ways. That's why the question should be asked there.

Comment: @techraf Normally, yes, but the sorts of things you use Ansible for are usually less trivial than in other cases. Like it needs to be able to install packages and such.

Comment: This is somewhat hopeless... I asked you if there was something special about Ansible - you replied it was not unique. Now you claim there are things that make it less trivial for Ansible. Anyway, let's leave it like that. The question does not belong here and OP has a record of being blatantly rude, so I, personally, am not going to help.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in general. Ansible uses the same ssh command under the hood.

Consider using dedicated box with some web/cli interface for non-admin folks to execute jobs. See [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) or [tower](https://www.ansible.com/tower) for example.